# Error inserting into database with Node.JS and SQL Server Always Encrypted

Tags: sql-server, node.js, azure, encryption, always-encrypted

I using a SQL Server database with the Always Encrypted features. When I try to insert a row, it fails and throws an error

```
let request = new Request(`INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_name] ([Name])
                           VALUES ('test')`,
                function (err, rowCount, rows) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log('errr--', err);
                    } else {
                        console.log(' row(s) ', rows);
                    }
                });
```

Error:

> RequestError: Operand type clash: varchar is incompatible with varchar(8000) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK_Auto1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'DrugstoreDB') collation_name = 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'_```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AlwaysEncrypted is client-side encryption, so must be supported by your client driver.  AFAIK the current list of client libraries that have implemented AlwaysEncrypted is:

-SqlClient for .NET Framework (but not .NET Core/.NET Standard)

-Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server for Windows

-Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server for Linux

-Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server

Comment: ca we use JDBC‌ for connect NodeJS App to SQL?

Comment: More likely there is a package for using ODBC from Node.js.